# How can I repair a granite countertop where multpile chunks have broken off?

Tags: bathroom, repair, damage, granite, countertops

A mirror door on the bathroom medicine cabinet broke off and took out a good chunk of granite countertop on the bathroom sink fixture. We're not talking about a crack or chip, not something small. We're talking about a good 3 or 4 multiple big chunks, all from the edge.

It looks something like this but about 3 times more damage.

[image: chipped granite]
<sub>(source: [seibertsmith.com](http://www.seibertsmith.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chippedgranite1.jpg))</sub>

Or this:

[image: chipped granite close-up]

Does Home Depot or Lowes have people who can repair countertops, or should I go Google searching for professionals in my area?

If I choose to do this myself, any idea on how and where I'd start? I'm more of a person good with electronics and computers. I wouldn't call myself a home improvement handyman type of guy but I'm willing to try and be patient and learn.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a normal size sink you can get up to 48" pieces for less than $100 and sometimes as little as $40-50 for a smaller top.  You aren't going to be happy paying money (you buying materials is $40) and then seeing that the granite with deformations and epoxy lines.  (craigslist has many people selling leftover granite sink tops)

Comment: Thank you, kindly. Even if I get these new pieces, I wouldn't know where to start to install them. I would imagine I need some tool that can cut these pieces to make it fit.

Answer (score 0):

That's no granite I've ever seen. Stone, sure, granite, I doubt. Oh - those are not YOUR countertop. OK.

**Find and Save all the chunks.**

1. Don't know, probably not a lot, other than the charge to make it worthwhile to even show up at your house. Perhaps less if you demount it and bring it to them.
2. I wouldn't trust them as far as I could throw them if they do, so I'd look for independents. YMMV. Old technology such as the yellow pages may work better than google here.
3. It will be an epoxy (glue) repair, much the same as countertop sections are joined with. The stone folks probably have "more ideal glue" available to them. Then you may need to sand and polish to clean up the glue lines.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I thought about undertaking this task myself. There are also very, very small pieces. Am I supposed to use these tiny pieces to mix with the epoxy? Is that how it works or can I simply apply the epoxy with a putty knife? Finally, what kind of clamp should I use, or can I get away with some Gorilla masking tape to hold it in place? Thank you, again!

Comment: You **said** 3-4 multiple big chunks. If you have tiny, tiny pieces, you may need a different approach - gluing large chunks back on, jigsaw-puzzle style, is practical, gluing tiny bits back on is less practical. A stone countertop supplier might be able to find similar stone, cut the edge, and glue a section of replacement stone in, if that is the case; or it may just not be practical.

Comment: Thank you. This is really great information! Yes, 3-4 multiple big chunks. I didn't count but there are very tiny pieces, as well, like the width of a hair (well not exactly but I think you get the analogy). They are so small that you might not see them. So, perhaps "jigsaw puzzle" style can still work. This is great info, again. Thank you.

Comment: @Ecnerwal are you sure that this can be repaired, because I’m almost certain that it can't be. Well maybe it can be glued back together but I think it will be ugly, fracture lines would be visible etc. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It can be repaired. A knowledgeable stone countertop installer can mix the epoxy with color and make the crack practically disappear. I have seen one installer mix 3 different colors, and place them in places that matched with the stone colors so the repair was nearly invisible. Leave the pros to do it. You could get the epoxy online to do it. I did for my stone countertops, blended my own colored epoxy and glued the sections together. Repairs with jagged breaks are a different story. You need to choose a glue that is runny in nature, too thick will not let you get the parts close enough.